# Checkbox Context Menu

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a ListView and an adapter in whick I create a linear layout and return as my created element.
When this linear layout is just TextViews, the context menu appears normally,
When I add a checkbox to the layout, the context menu isn't shown.
Is there any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that when there is a clickable element on your ListView, like a checkbox, that element handles clicks, not the ListView.  Thus, you would need to add the context menu to the checkbox, not the ListView.  Since a TextView is not clickable, it allows the click to pass through to the ListView.